# Product function exercise.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For $x\ne 1$ show that

$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+x^{2^{k-1}}\right) = \frac{1-x^{2^{n}}}{1-x}
$$

Comment: The product index is $n$ but no $n$ occurs in the multiplied factor, Needs correction. Maybe index is &k$?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the product, we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k - 1} } } \right)}  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k_{\,0} \, < \,\,n} {x^{\,2^{\,k_{\,0} } } }  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k_{\,0}  < \,\,k_{\,1} \, < \,\,n} {x^{\,2^{\,k_{\,0} }  + 2^{\,k_{\,1} } } }
  +  \cdots  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k_{\,0}  < \,\,k_{\,1} \, \cdots \, < \,\,k_{\,n}  < \,\,n} {x^{\,2^{\,k_{\,0} }  + 2^{\,k_{\,1} }  +  \cdots  + 2^{\,k_{\,n} } } }  \cr} 
$$
as can be easily seen when proceeding recursively.

The set of exponents
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ {\,2^{\,k_{\,0} }  + 2^{\,k_{\,1} }  +  \cdots  + 2^{\,k_{\,q} } \quad \left| {\;0\, \le \,k_{\,0}  < \,\,k_{\,1} \, \cdots \, < \,\,k_{\,q}  < \,\,n} \right.} \right\}
\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ {\underbrace {\left( { \cdots 0, \cdots ,0,1,0 \cdots ,1, \cdots } \right)_{\,2} }_{n\,{\rm bits},\;q\,{\rm ones}}} \right\} \cr} 
$$
when represented in base $2$, corresponds to the set of all the binary strings
of length $n$ having $q$ one bits.

At varying of $q$ we get the whole set of binary strings of length $n$ (without holes and without duplications):
$$
\left\{ {\left( {0,0, \cdots ,0, \cdots ,0} \right)_{\,2} , \cdots ,\left( {0, \cdots ,0,1,0, \cdots ,0} \right)_{\,2} , \cdots ,\left( {1,1, \cdots ,1, \cdots ,1} \right)_{\,2} } \right\}
$$
that is, the representation of all the digits in $[0,2^{(n-1)+1}-1]=[0,2^n-1]$.

Therefore
$$
\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j < \,\,2^{\,n}  - 1} {x^{\,j} }  = {{1 - x^{\,2^{\,n} } } \over {1 - x}}
$$

Refer to this interesting ["Lectures on Integer Partitions"- H. S. Wilf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf), at page 8.

Comment: Can you be more analytic in the third row - i get confused with parenthesis...

Comment: @VaggelisKyrilas: you are right, my answer was too much summarized: I expanded the steps.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by induction. $n=1$ is obvious, for $n+1$ we have:

$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1+x^{2^{k-1}}\right)=(1+x^{2^n})\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+x^{2^{k-1}}\right)=(1+x^{2^n})\frac{1-x^{2^n}}{1-x}=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}$$